# Bullet collision detection in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

For my first years of studies, i have a Three.js project. I have to create a little fps. I have followed a tutorial, everything is fine except the bullet collision detection. I try some stuff i have found on internet, follow some tutorial trying to understand as much as i can, because i don't want to just copy and paste stuff.

But i have to confess i am a bit lost. Here is the code i have develop. What i want to do is to detect when a bullet touch another object. Like for example make disappear a box when a bullet touch it.

The bullet are defined like this :

```
 var bullet = new THREE.Mesh(
 new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05,8,8),
 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff})
```

Here is also my code

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, mesh, clock;
var meshFloor, ambientLight, light;

var crate, crateTexture, crateNormalMap, crateBumpMap;

var keyboard = {};
var player = { height:1.8, speed:0.2, turnSpeed:Math.PI*0.02, canShoot:0 };
var USE_WIREFRAME = false;

var loadingScreen = {
 scene: new THREE.Scene(),
 camera: new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, 1280/720, 0.1, 100),
 box: new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5,0.5,0.5),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0x4444ff })
 )
};
var loadingManager = null;
var RESOURCES_LOADED = false;

// Models index
var models = {
 tent: {
  obj:"models/Tent_Poles_01.obj",
  mtl:"models/Tent_Poles_01.mtl",
  mesh: null
 },
 campfire: {
  obj:"models/Campfire_01.obj",
  mtl:"models/Campfire_01.mtl",
  mesh: null
 },
 pirateship: {
  obj:"models/Pirateship.obj",
  mtl:"models/Pirateship.mtl",
  mesh: null
 },
 uzi: {
  obj:"models/uziGold.obj",
  mtl:"models/uziGold.mtl",
  mesh: null,
  castShadow:false
 }
};

// Meshes index
var meshes = {};

// Bullets array
var bullets = [];

function init(){
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, 1280/720, 0.1, 1000);
 clock = new THREE.Clock();
 
 loadingScreen.box.position.set(0,0,5);
 loadingScreen.camera.lookAt(loadingScreen.box.position);
 loadingScreen.scene.add(loadingScreen.box);
 
 loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
 loadingManager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total){
  console.log(item, loaded, total);
 };
 loadingManager.onLoad = function(){
  console.log("loaded all resources");
  RESOURCES_LOADED = true;
  onResourcesLoaded();
 };
 
 
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xff4444, wireframe:USE_WIREFRAME})
 );
 mesh.position.y += 1;
 mesh.receiveShadow = true;
 mesh.castShadow = true;
 //scene.add(mesh);
 
 meshFloor = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20,20, 10,10),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xffffff, wireframe:USE_WIREFRAME})
 );
 meshFloor.rotation.x -= Math.PI / 2;
 meshFloor.receiveShadow = true;
 scene.add(meshFloor);
 
 
 ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
 scene.add(ambientLight);
 
 light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8, 18);
 light.position.set(-3,6,-3);
 light.castShadow = true;
 light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
 light.shadow.camera.far = 25;
 scene.add(light);
 
 
 var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(loadingManager);
 crateTexture = textureLoader.load("crate0/crate0_diffuse.jpg");
 crateBumpMap = textureLoader.load("crate0/crate0_bump.jpg");
 crateNormalMap = textureLoader.load("crate0/crate0_normal.jpg");
 
 crate = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(3,3,3),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
   color:0xffffff,
   map:crateTexture,
   bumpMap:crateBumpMap,
   normalMap:crateNormalMap
  })
 );

 crate.position.set(2.5, 3/2, 2.5);
 crate.receiveShadow = true;
 crate.castShadow = true;
 
 // Load models
 // REMEMBER: Loading in Javascript is asynchronous, so you need
 // to wrap the code in a function and pass it the index. If you
 // don't, then the index '_key' can change while the model is being
 // downloaded, and so the wrong model will be matched with the wrong
 // index key.
 for( var _key in models ){
  (function(key){
   
   var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader(loadingManager);
   mtlLoader.load(models[key].mtl, function(materials){
    materials.preload();
    
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(loadingManager);
    
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.load(models[key].obj, function(mesh){
     
     mesh.traverse(function(node){
      if( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ){
       if('castShadow' in models[key])
        node.castShadow = models[key].castShadow;
       else
        node.castShadow = true;
       
       if('receiveShadow' in models[key])
        node.receiveShadow = models[key].receiveShadow;
       else
        node.receiveShadow = true;
      }
     });
     models[key].mesh = mesh;
     
    });
   });
   
  })(_key);
 }
 
 
 camera.position.set(0, player.height, -5);
 camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,player.height,0));
 
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setSize(1280, 720);

 renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
 renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap;
 
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 
 animate();
}

// Runs when all resources are loaded
function onResourcesLoaded(){
 
 // Clone models into meshes.
 meshes["tent1"] = models.tent.mesh.clone();
 meshes["tent2"] = models.tent.mesh.clone();
 meshes["campfire1"] = models.campfire.mesh.clone();
 meshes["campfire2"] = models.campfire.mesh.clone();
 
 // Reposition individual meshes, then add meshes to scene
 meshes["tent1"].position.set(-5, 0, 4);
 scene.add(meshes["tent1"]);
 
 meshes["tent2"].position.set(-8, 0, 4);
 scene.add(meshes["tent2"]);
 
 meshes["campfire1"].position.set(-5, 0, 1);
 meshes["campfire2"].position.set(-8, 0, 1);
 
 scene.add(meshes["campfire1"]);
 scene.add(meshes["campfire2"]);
 
 // player weapon
 meshes["playerweapon"] = models.uzi.mesh.clone();
 meshes["playerweapon"].position.set(0,2,0);
 meshes["playerweapon"].scale.set(10,10,10);
 scene.add(meshes["playerweapon"]);
}

function animate(){

 // Play the loading screen until resources are loaded.
 if( RESOURCES_LOADED == false ){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  loadingScreen.box.position.x -= 0.05;
  if( loadingScreen.box.position.x < -10 ) loadingScreen.box.position.x = 10;
  loadingScreen.box.position.y = Math.sin(loadingScreen.box.position.x);
  
  renderer.render(loadingScreen.scene, loadingScreen.camera);
  return;
 }

 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 
 var time = Date.now() * 0.0005;
 var delta = clock.getDelta();
 
 mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
 mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
 crate.rotation.y += 0.01;
 // Uncomment for absurdity!
 // meshes["pirateship"].rotation.z += 0.01;
 
 // go through bullets array and update position
 // remove bullets when appropriate
 for(var index=0; index<bullets.length; index+=1){
  if( bullets[index] === undefined ) continue;
  if( bullets[index].alive == false ){
   bullets.splice(index,1);
   continue;
  }
  
  bullets[index].position.add(bullets[index].velocity);
 }
 
 if(keyboard[38]){ // UP button 
  camera.position.x -= Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
  camera.position.z -= -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
 }
 if(keyboard[40]){ // DOWN button
  camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
  camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
 }
 if(keyboard[65]){ // A key
  camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI/2) * player.speed;
  camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI/2) * player.speed;
 }
 if(keyboard[68]){ // D key
  camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y - Math.PI/2) * player.speed;
  camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y - Math.PI/2) * player.speed;
 }
 
 if(keyboard[37]){ // left arrow key
  camera.rotation.y -= player.turnSpeed;
 }
 if(keyboard[39]){ // right arrow key
  camera.rotation.y += player.turnSpeed;
 }
 
 // shoot a bullet
 if(keyboard[32] && player.canShoot <= 0){ // spacebar key
  // creates a bullet as a Mesh object
  var bullet = new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05,8,8),
   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff})
  );
  // this is silly.
  // var bullet = models.pirateship.mesh.clone();
  
  // position the bullet to come from the player's weapon
  bullet.position.set(
   meshes["playerweapon"].position.x + 0.0 ,
   meshes["playerweapon"].position.y + 0.10,
   meshes["playerweapon"].position.z + 0.1
  );
  
  // set the velocity of the bullet
  bullet.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(
   -Math.sin(camera.rotation.y),
   0,
   Math.cos(camera.rotation.y)
  );
  
  // after 1000ms, set alive to false and remove from scene
  // setting alive to false flags our update code to remove
  // the bullet from the bullets array
  bullet.alive = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
   bullet.alive = false;
   scene.remove(bullet);
  }, 1000);
  
  // add to scene, array, and set the delay to 10 frames
  bullets.push(bullet);
  scene.add(bullet);
  player.canShoot = 10;
 }
 if(player.canShoot > 0) player.canShoot -= 1;
 
 // position the gun in front of the camera
 meshes["playerweapon"].position.set(
  camera.position.x - Math.sin(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI/6) * 0.75,
  camera.position.y - 0.5 + Math.sin(time*4 + camera.position.x + camera.position.z)*0.01,
  camera.position.z + Math.cos(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI/6) * 0.75
 );
 meshes["playerweapon"].rotation.set(
  camera.rotation.x,
  camera.rotation.y - Math.PI,
  camera.rotation.z
 );
 
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function keyDown(event){
 keyboard[event.keyCode] = true;
}

function keyUp(event){
 keyboard[event.keyCode] = false;
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);

window.onload = init;
```

Here is a fiddle with the code i have already developed:

https://jsfiddle.net/Mxfrd/bany0afg/

If someone have an idea how can i do that, it will be super ! i am very lost on that point.

Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle is broken because jsfiddle knows nothing about your relative paths. Also, please include your code in your post, because if your fiddle goes away, so the the context of your question.

Comment: Bullet collisions are not quite the same as mesh collision. Bullets travel fast. A mesh's position is changed per animation frame, and it's possible that a small object may pass through another object between frames. For high-speed collisions it's advisable to utilize raycasting for a simple FPS. This is not an answer, just some guidance. There are also libraries out there such as ammo.js which can help out.

Comment: @Radio while not an answer, it is _the_ answer. A raycast should be used intead of detecting mesh collisions because it's possible the bullet mesh just 'teleports' from one side of the object to the other. To simulate a velocity, you could vary the range of the raycaster.